# How can I remove duplicates from a table in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have designed an Access DB that has a main table which has products coming in and out.
The table shows the individual item coming into stock, and is issues a stock No. which is unique.
A second record is then created when the item is sold or transferred (but it retains the same stock No.)

The "double entry" is so that a record can be kept of the purchase details, and subsequently the sale details for each stock item.

I have been trying to design a stock query to show all current stock, in essence only showing the stock numbers which have not been sold.

Every time I try and create the query, I can easily exclude all the Sold stock, but of course I am left with the original purchase record within the table, which I cannot remove.

I have managed to create a query thats shows all duplicates, but I cannot find a way to remove these records from my query table to produce the stock level I require.

I would be grateful for any thoughts, and if you could keep it in laymans terms if possible, I am what you could turn a hobbyist at DB's and although learning, have a long way to go.

Many Thanks

Comment: The schema would be useful along with some sample data and the desired output. Ps _item coming into stock, and is issues a stock No. which is unique. A second record is then created when the item is sold or transferred (but it retains the same stock No.)_ so it's not unique any more?

Comment: And why is this tagged with mysql and sql-server when you are clearly working with Access 2010?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(StockNumber) as StockCount, StockNumber FROM StockTable GROUP BY StockNumber HAVING COUNT(StockNumber) = 1` would group stock items and count them, then filters where there is a single record, i.e. it hasn't got a corresponding sold record.

Comment: I've replaced product tags. If you insist on having `mysql` and `sql-server` attached to your question, please make sure you've justified (in your question) their relevance.

Comment: Tanner, thank you for your suggestion, I will have a look at that today.